# AspxListBox's selected item is null however I select an item

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

I use AspxListBox. I select an item but selected item is null in OnSelectedIndexChanged event on server side. I checked, I don't clear list box items. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @ cagin-can you post some code perhaps you are binding the listbox on every postback so the item is not retrieved in code behind. try to put binding logic in if(!Ispotback){} block

Comment: @Devjosh, I checked it but I don't bind the listbox on every postback.

Comment: Please post complete ASPxListBox definition and data-binding code

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ViewState enabled? If not you may have to make sure you re-bind the data.

Comment: ListBox's EnabelViewState property is True

Answer (score -1):

I don know whether you have kept your autopostback = true for your asplistbox, Try it, if havnt tried it yet.